# Javascript, add more values than one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, insert, addition

Hello :) I need your help with javascript code. I am trying add more values in my javascript code.  There my code: example i want add value te_id=$te_id. Please help and show me how i can add more than one value. 
Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function loading_show(){
                $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
            }
            function loading_hide(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
            }                
            function loadData(page){
                loading_show();                    
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#main_conter").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#main_conter").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
            $('#main_conter .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);

            });           
            $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what brother what do you want?

Comment: Add more values? What? I'm guessing most of the code you posted isn't relevant.

Comment: "add more values" ? please be more specific

Comment: FYI, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. You should convert to `.on()`.

Comment: data: "page="+page, 
there need send other value

Comment: Up vote for a valid question. I'm sure it's a duplicate of an answer somewhere on here but I don't have the means right now to look

Comment: I found other question with this code, but the same not working :(

Comment: What jquery version are you using? What format is the response coming back in? both these things in my experience can effect if you can see the data. If you are using google chrome, I would suggest looking at the developer tools by pressing f12 and under network check and see if it is success fully making the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly simple. You can add multiple values to your data field data: "page"+page+"&a="+a
Treat it like a as far as the formatting, meaning separate each data set by a '&' that will allow you to send multiple data values to the server in your ajax.

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_data.php",
    data: "page"+page+"&a="+a,
    success: function(msg)
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: Not working you solution.